# Phase Portrait vs Explicit Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Currently revising Ordinary Differential equations and I seem to have come across a contradiction[image]

[image]

[image]

Now my confusion comes with the sign of $x_0$ surely using the phase portraits if $x_0 < k$ when $k <0$ the solution will tend to negative infinity and the same thought for the second case where $k>0$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_0<k<0$, then $x(t) \to -\infty$ **in finite time**, namely when the denominator $x_0(e^{kt}-1)+k$ becomes zero (which happens for a unique $t=t_0>0$).

After a blow-up like this, it probably doesn't make much sense to continue the solution to $t>t_0$, since whatever it is you're modelling, the model has likely ceased to be valid, but if you *do* continue the solution using the same formula for $x(t)$, then $x(t)$ comes back from $+\infty$, so to speak, and decays to zero as $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: Thankyou so much for this explanation, makes so much more sense now!

Comment: You're welcome!